# How to use CMPedometer and store data server side while ensuring integrity of steps?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I'm working on a test app for learning Swift/iOS dev where I'm trying to create a step tracker game where you win if you get the most steps over a week. However, I'm not sure how to do this in respect to being able to trust the step data the client sends. As of now, I am using CMPedometer to track steps and upload them periodically to the server, but technically a smart user could game the system even if I added some encryption.

Is there a way that I can pull this data rather than waiting for the client to send it? or use the data in a way that I can trust it's not forged by the user?

As of now my API simply expects something like {"steps":123} and some other unimportant data to store data for the logged in user. But I realize how vulnerable this is.

Comment: Can you explain this vulnerability?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/validating_apps_that_connect_to_your_server